# Sorting citations in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

The output im trying to get
[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Ref}
\author{Ref}
\begin{document}

There is a very useful mathematics text book for engineering students written by Erwin Kreysig \cite{aem}. For those of you interested in the hazard from \textit{Clostridium botulinum} associated with 
Alaskan native foods should refer to. For information on fast index assignment algorithm that uses quadratic assignment, see 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

References:

```
@book{aem,
    title={Advance Engineering Mathematics},
    author={Erwin Kreyszig},
    edition={6th},
    year={1988}
    }
    
@inproceedings{speech,
    title={A quadratic index assignment algorithm for vector quantisation over noisy transmission channels},
    author={Nicola Talbot and Gavin Cawley},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the Institute of Acoustics Autumn Conference on Speech and Hearing},
    volume={18},
    pages={195--199},
    month=nov,
    year={1996}
    }

@incollection{image,
    title={A fast index assignment algorithm for robust vector quantisation over noisy transmission channels},
    author={Gavin Cawley and Nicola Talbot},
    publisher={Santa Barbara},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the I.E.E.E International Conference on Image Processing},
    address={California, USA},
    month=oct,
    year={1997}
    }

@article{noise,
    title={A fast index assignment algorithm for robust vector quantisation over noisy transmission channels},
    author={Gavin Cawley and Nicola Talbot},
    journal={I.E.E Electronic Letters},
    volume={32},
    pages={1343--1344},
    number=15,
    month=jul,
    year={1996}
    }
```

Im having trouble with the 5th reference in the image
and how to sort the citations and get the output [3,1,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand, your bib file contains mistakes (authors order is important…). And to cite multiple references, just use `\cite{<key1>,<key2>,…,<keyN>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Ref}
\author{Ref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%[2]
@book{aem,
    title={Advanced Engineering Mathematics},
    author={Kreyszig, Erwin},
    publisher={Wiley},
    edition={6th},
    year={1988}
}
%[3]
@inproceedings{speech,
    title={A quadratic index assignment algorithm for vector quantisation over noisy transmission channels},
    author={Talbot, Nicola and Cawley, Gavin},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the Institute of Acoustics Autumn Conference on Speech and Hearing},
    volume={18},
    pages={195--199},
    month=nov,
    year={1996}
}
%[4]
@incollection{image,
    title={A fast index assignment algorithm for robust vector quantisation of image data},
    author={Talbot, Nicola and Cawley, Gavin},
    publisher={Santa Barbara},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the I.E.E.E International Conference on Image Processing},
    address={California, USA},
    month=oct,
    year={1997}
}
%[1]
@article{noise,
    title={A fast index assignment algorithm for vector quantization over noisy transmission channels},
    author={Cawley, Gavin and Talbot, Nicola},
    journal={I.E.E Electronic Letters},
    volume={32},
    pages={1343--1344},
    number=15,
    month=jul,
    year={1996}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
    There is a very useful mathematics text book for engineering students written by Erwin Kreysig \cite{aem}. For those of you interested in the hazard from \textit{Clostridium botulinum} associated with 
    Alaskan native foods should refer to. For information on fast index assignment algorithm that uses quadratic assignment, see \cite{speech,noise,image}.
    
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

### Edit

Add the 5th reference and use `biblatex`. Run with `biber` and be sure having an updated `.bib` file.

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}\usepackage[%
language=english,
%   defernumbers=true,
backend=biber,
%   backend=bibtex,
%   sorting=ynt,
sorting=nyt,
%   url=false,
%backref=true,
    style=numeric,
]{biblatex}

\title{Ref}
\author{Ref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%[2]
@book{aem,
    title={Advanced Engineering Mathematics},
    author={Kreyszig, Erwin},
    publisher={Wiley},
    edition={6th},
    year={1988}
}
%[3]
@inproceedings{speech,
    title={A quadratic index assignment algorithm for vector quantisation over noisy transmission channels},
    author={Talbot, Nicola and Cawley, Gavin},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the Institute of Acoustics Autumn Conference on Speech and Hearing},
    volume={18},
    pages={195--199},
    month=nov,
    year={1996}
}
%[4]
@incollection{image,
    title={A fast index assignment algorithm for robust vector quantisation of image data},
    author={Talbot, Nicola and Cawley, Gavin},
    publisher={Santa Barbara},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the I.E.E.E International Conference on Image Processing},
    address={California, USA},
    month=oct,
    year={1997}
}
%[1]
@article{noise,
    title={A fast index assignment algorithm for vector quantization over noisy transmission channels},
    author={Cawley, Gavin and Talbot, Nicola},
    journal={I.E.E Electronic Letters},
    volume={32},
    pages={1343--1344},
    number=15,
    month=jul,
    year={1996}
}
@inbook{Wainwright1993,
    author = {Wainwright, Robert B.},
    title = {Hazards from northern native foods},
    booktitle = {Clostridium botulinum : ecology and control in foods},
    year = {1993},
    bookauthor = {Hauschild, Andreas, H. W. and Dodds, Karen, L.},
    publisher = {M. Dekker},
    language = {english},
    location = {New York},
    chapter = {12},
    pages = {305-322},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    
    There is a very useful mathematics text book for engineering students written by Erwin Kreysig \cite{aem}. For those of you interested in the hazard from \textit{Clostridium botulinum} associated with 
    Alaskan native foods should refer to. For information on fast index assignment algorithm that uses quadratic assignment, see \cite{speech,noise,image}.
    
    And \cite{Wainwright1993}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, the keys you choose are not really easy to use… I prefer something like <First author last name><year> plus a letter in case there are several publications in the same year.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kain if this answers your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sorry im new 